# Django secondary admin site links to main admin site

Tags: django

I'm trying to add a secondary admin site and it's working correctly except that any links are pointing to the main admin site. Not sure how to get around this.

If I visit `/dispatch/admin/` the model `Run` is visible but when I click the link it directs me to `/admin/dispatch/run/` instead of `/dispatch/admin/dispatch/run/`.

Django==3.2.7

```
class DispatchAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    pass


class DispatchRunAdmin(RunAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return (
            super().get_queryset(request)
            .filter_today_or_future()
        )

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return [f.name for f in self.model._meta.fields]


dispatch_admin_site = DispatchAdminSite(name='Dispatch')
dispatch_admin_site.register(models.Run, DispatchRunAdmin)
```

dispatch/urls.py

```
app_name = 'dispatch'
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.dispatch_admin_site.urls),
]
```

project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dispatch/', include('dispatch.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason the custom admin can't be added using `include` it has to be a top level URL in your project.

```
# project/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from dispatch.admin import dispatch_admin_site

urlpatterns = [
    path('dispatch-admin/', dispatch_admin_site.urls),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```